# Why was the movie titled "Youth"?

Tags: title, youth

I saw the movie, [*Youth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3312830/) (2015) and there appears to be no scene or context related to this title.

It is a story about a retired music composer, Fred and Mick Boyle the movie director.

So why was the movie titled “Youth?”

Comment: [It is a story of the eternal struggle between age and youth, the past and the future, life and death, commitment and betrayal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_(2015_film)).

Answer (score 1):

According to the film's director, it was titled 'Youth' because the freedom to choose your own path is *akin to youthfulness*, even among those who are older.

> When asked about the film’s title, Sorrentino explained: “The film’s
> idea is how we think about future, how the future always offers a
> possibility of liberty, and liberty is a state inherent to youth”. To
> live thinking that the next day contains freedom doesn’t mean living
> under the banners of “YOLO” and “FOMO”, but “to live knowing that in
> theory you could do anything — without necessarily doing it”.
>
> <sub><sup>[On Paolo Sorrentino’s latest film,“Youth”, and its place among earlier works](https://medium.com/@katiazoritch/paolo-sorrentino-perhaps-youth-depends-on-a-walk-around-the-lake-dc077f088cd2#.fk1d06jh5)</sup></sub>